# Spacy error in loading pretrained custom model with entity rulers and ner pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I used a spacy blank model with Gensim custom word vectors. Then I trained the model to get the pipeline in the respective order-

entityruler1, ner1, entity ruler2, ner2

After training it, I saved it in a folder through

`nlp.to_disk('path to folder')`

However, if I try to load the same model using
`nlp1 = spacy.load('path to folder')`
It gives me this error-

`ValueError: [E109] Model for component 'ner' not initialized. Did you forget to load a model, or forget to call begin_training()?`

I cannot find any solution online. What might be the reason I am getting this? How do I successfully load and use my pretrained model?

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having trouble. In order to help you though we'll need more info - what version of spaCy are you using, are you using Transformers, etc. Maybe try opening a Discussion on the spaCy repo. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions

Comment: I am using spacy version 2.2.4. I trained a corpus for custom word vectors  using Gensim's Word2vec.
Then I loaded a blank spacy model containing those words vectors. That's it. 
I think it has something to do with the entityrulers. If i disable them and only save the ner pipes, then I can load the model. Sure, I'll open a discussion there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to spacy version 2.3.7 resolved this error. :)